# Linux TCP Stack - notification for peer reset or broken connection

Tags: linux, tcp, notifications, reset, disconnect

I have a situation -

There is a TCP connection between A-->B in established state. A sends a few bytes to B and then terminates itself. The B is neither doing send() or recv().

**I would like to know if there is a way to know that the connection is broken.**

I know that, for broken connections recv() returns '0'. But in the above situation - A has sent some data to B, so the first (one or multiple) recv() would return me the sent data and finally I would get recv() == 0. But I want to know about the broken connection, without having to pump-out all data from the recv-buffer.

1. I would like to get a notification about the incoming FIN/RST packets
2. I have keep-alive activated, so I would like to get a notification when the keep-alive packet is unreplied by the partner

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want to check for the live connection you can try `send(fd, buf, 0, 0)` i.e send 0 bytes of data. If connection is broken it would fail.

Comment: If the cconnection is *already known to be broken* at this end it may fail. For example, if there has already been a retransmission timeout, or an RST has been received. This technique won't detect a connection that has just been broken after successful transfers.

Comment: Furthermore... I need some 'notification' from the stack when the connection is broken. The design is such that it is not suitable to query the stack via send() or recv().

Comment: @pppsandeep Bad luck, there isn't any such thing in TCP.